# How can I implement a University like timetable in asp.net with c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on a project that I have to implement a timetable tool.

I am using ASP.NET with C#. I tried to implement my timetable with the GridView control. I wanted to retrieve information from my database to each timeslot(box) of the gridview but instead I only managed to put the information in each line.

What control should I use to implement my timetable and how?
I am very new to the .NET programming, can you help me?

This is a link that has something similar to what I want. Instead of a monthly calendar I want to implement a timetable for one week only. And instead using visual basic as in the example in the link I am using C#.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/schedule.aspx

Here is some information of my database and how I want to implement my timetable:

#### courses:

```
courseID(identity - auto increment)           courseRef
               1                                c0006
               2                                c0007
               3                                c0008
               4                                c0009
               5                                c0010
               6                                c0011
               7                                c0012
               8                                c0013
```

and so on...

#### rooms

```
roomed(identity – auto increment)    roomRef     roomSize    building
        1                                rC          100          1
        2                                rF           30          1
        3                                rG           20          0 
        4                                rO           12          0
```

and so on...

#### Teachers

```
teacherID(identity – auto increment)       teacherRef
                1                             t000
                2                             t002
                3                             t003
                4                             t004
                5                             t005
                6                             t006
                7                             t007
```

and so on...

And then I have a table that describes each course. For example who is teaching the course, how many students are in the course,  the number of lectures the course needs each week and the minimum days that the lectures of each course should take place:

#### courseDescription:

```
courseID   teacherID   noOfLectures    minDays   noOfStudents
    1          1            2             2           75
    2          2            2             2           75
    3          3            9             4           75
    4          4            7             2           75
    5          5            3             3           65
    6          6            9             4           65
    7          7            8             4           65
```

---

The timetable that I am looking for is a 2D timetable like this:

http://www.imagebam.com/image/9761dc26297272

Each timeslot it will display the information like the table above.

I have not finished my database yet because I don’t know how I will represent the periods and the timeslots. If you have any ideas how I will represent them in my database that will be helpful. If you thing that I have to change something in my database I would like to hear your advice.

My problem is that I don’t know how I will implement this table and show the data from my database in each square of the timetable table.

I hope I gave enough information. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using two Repeater (asp:Repeater) controls inside eachother.

The first Repeater loops over the days in the week. The second Repeater loops over the hours in a given day. Then write the html from that.

The html could be structured as an html table with rowspan set on the table cells to indicate the duration of the class.