# Free schedule/timetable GUI library for .NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, user-interface, schedule

Does anyone know of any good free libraries providing Windows Forms controls for displaying schedules/timetables in .NET? I'm really looking for something similar to what the guy who asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533415/how-can-i-implement-a-university-like-timetable-in-asp-net-with-c) was seeking, with a couple of differences:

1. I don't need any help organizing the underlying data or generating the schedule (that's all set) -- I just want a clean way of displaying it.
2. I'm actually looking for a custom control in Windows Forms, not an ASP.NET control.

One thing I've considered doing is just using a TableLayoutPanel control, but ideally I'm looking for something that will be more straightforward code-wise (as in, something actually designed for displaying a timetable) and sharper-looking visually.

Comment: Have you seen any programs/products that look like what you want?

Comment: The library linked to in the question I referred to (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/custom-controls/schedule.aspx) looks very much like what I would want, except that it is for ASP.NET and not Windows Forms. I am unfamiliar with ASP.NET; maybe it's possible for me to use that library in a Windows application. If so, my question should be changed: how do I use an ASP.NET control in a Windows Forms app?

Comment: Did you ever find a good solution?

Answer (score 2):

How about [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/Calendardayview.aspx) control?  It is very similar to the calendar in Outlook.  It does come with source code, so if it's not quite what you need you could maybe use this as a base for your own implementation.

Comment: That looks promising, although it makes me a bit nervous as it sounds from what the developer said like it's only half finished. Still, as you pointed out, it's open source. I'll check it out -- thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Download the source code for  http://www.monocalendar.com
He built a control (CalWidget) that you can easily recompile in your own project that's pretty nice.  I recompiled it in .net 4.0 with little problems.

Comment: Wow, that looks awesome. Thanks a lot; I will check this out and accept your answer if it's as good as it looks!

Comment: After you get it compiled in your own project, one thing that took me a while to figure out was to set the Alpha property to 50 (it defaults to zero) and set the current calender selected to true.  I can send you some sample code when I get home tonight if you want it.  I did discover last night that it doesn't currently handle complicated repeating meetings.  But since I have the source code that can be fixed :-)