# Visual basic CalWidget.dll settings

Tags: vb.net, winforms, calendar, winforms-interop

I'm new at this.
I would like to use in my visual studio project calwidget dll.
I add the dll to my project and i was able to edit some properties but i don't know how to create/save/retrieve appointments (similar to the outlook style).

Create more than one calendar (in monocalendar.exe you can create more than one calendar)

I just found this thread

[Free schedule/timetable GUI library for .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987678/free-schedule-timetable-gui-library-for-net)

But unfortunetly wasn't helpful (probably because of my beginner level)

Can anyone please give me some advice or help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To use the dll, you need to refer it first.
In Visual Studio 2012 (others too) go to:
Project-->Add Reference --> Click on Browse button and browse your DLL.

Once you refer to DLL, use Import statement in your code to refer to the DLL library.

To create more than one calander, You can create more than one intance of the class or usre one winform per user. It is something depend on your application.

As I promised a sample code, I have done a video on the same. I am not sure if you were able to follow my instructions above. So I put those all here. [Click Here...](https://youtu.be/BUZMFvs0zZY)

Comment: Thank you so much for your advice. I used the import statement and found something new that i still don't know how to manage. could you please give some other suggestions abuot these properties? or otherwise how could i open the dll file to look inside and see how the dll manage these statements?

Comment: If you are looking for this   Control (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12201/Calendar-DayView-Control) , probably you get a new control by drag and drop DLL into the toolbar panel, or right click the toolbar panel and select option 'Choose Items'. and browse DLL. This will get you the control. Drag and Drop it on your form. Rest you can follow on link. If this solve your problem feel free to vote and accept my answer.

Comment: again thanks a lot. I'm trying to follow your suggestions and even the ones i found in the link. I got the dll into my project but I'm not able to work with it. Moreover the article and the project are written with C while i'm using the vb.net. I tried to translate the code but i got different errors and i don't know how to manage them.

Comment: When you import DLL into your project, irrespective to the language, you can use dll function. If yo can see the control, you can use it's properties just like any other control. If not, go into code view and create object of DLL class and use it as you need. basically try any of these. A. dim ctrl as new DLLNAME.CLASSNAME or to cll function of  a class DLLNAME.FUNCTION. Do not forget to import dll in your code.

Comment: Hi I spent the last few days trying to interact with the dll following your suggestions.Unfortunately I didn't get anything working. If it's not a problem for you, could you please post some code to help me (i.e. adding a new appointment to the dll). I'm sure in that way you could help me understanding the concepts you're trying to explain me. thanks.

Comment: Hi did you find some kind of example that could help me?
I'm still trying to learn how to interact with the dll but i'm getting anywhere.
Every kind of help would be helpfull!
Thanks a lot

Comment: Every DLL is different in it's function, but objectve is the same. DLL used to load functions, resurces dynamically on the run time without exposing the code into application developers. I will try to see if I can do a quick code.

Comment: Check the revised Answer and Mark as answer if you find it helpful anyways.